# How to resolve a segmentation fault for the following code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, output

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        int num, xval;
        int sum=0,j=1,p;
        printf("Enter number of terms: ");
        scanf("%d",num);
        printf("Enter value of x: ");
        scanf("%d",xval);
        for(int i=1;i<=num;i++){
            p=pow(xval,j);
            j=j+2;
            if(i%2==0)
                sum=sum-p;
            }
            else{
                sum=sum+p;
            }
        }
        printf("Sum of the series is: %d",sum);
        return 0;
}
```

The question was to find the sum of n terms of the sin series: sin(x) = x - x3 + x5 – x7.

Comment: You need the address of the variables in `scanf`, such as `scanf("%d",&num);`.

Comment: If you are computing a **sine** series, you must work with `double`, not `int`. But the series you show isn't a sine series. It lacks the factorial divisors.